# How to print the relationship types contained in a graph

Tags: python, neo4j, py2neo

Here is another basic question for some basic functionality of py2neo (v4) that does not work in the intuitive way.

> How to get/print the list of existing relationship types?

In the [documentation's graph section of the database page](https://py2neo.org/v4/database.html#py2neo.database.Schema.relationship_types) there is a method `relationship_types` which supposedly returns "The set of relationship types currently defined within the graph.", and I expected it to work like this:

```
print(graph.relationship_types)
```

but I get the error `'Graph' object has no attribute 'relationship_types'`.

But if that's the case, what does have that attribute?  There is no example of using this method on that page (or anywhere else I could find), and I am having trouble with a lot of the basic functionality of py2neo for similar reasons.

Comment: you should check your py2neo version. The same property works for me on V4.1.0
Also, can you share your entire code

Comment: I checked and I am also using v4.1.0.  My entire code is just like below.

Answer (score 2):

```
for rel in grap.ralationships:
    print('from:',rel.start_node)
    print('to:',rel.end_node)
    print('drum role.... ding ding ding Rel TYPE:',type(r).__name__)
```

list of types of rels:

```
set([type(r).__name__ for r in in graph.ralationships])
```

hope this helps some one

Answer (score 0):

The property that you mentioned is not only in V4 but in V3 as well.
Chances are that you are not using the property properly.

Here is a really simple example which works for me (v3.1.2). Same code is working on V4.1.0 too.

```
from py2neo import Graph

graph = Graph("http://localhost:7474", username="USERNAME", password="PASSWORD")

print(graph.relationship_types)
```

Comment: I ran just this code (changing the credentials to match my database, of course), and I get the same error: `'Graph' object has no attribute 'relationship_types'`.  getting the info in Cypher from the Neo4j browser worked without trouble.

Comment: @AaronBramson When running the program can you import py2neo and then print(py2neo.__version__) . Just want to make sure the version is same.

Comment: Yeah, I wrote it in the comment above, the version is 4.1.0

Comment: just trying to make sure that you are running the command with the right python installation in case you have multiple Python installations. Also, have you tried reinstalling the module?

Comment: Yes, I'm running with the right python installation.  So far this is the only thing that's broken in py2neo (besides the documentation and currently their website), and I can get the info with cypher, so I'm not going to waste more time with it.  It seems to be just a bug.